# How to run SQL Query on webpage with Sheetjs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, alasql, sheetjs

I'm making a project for my internship. And I need to run SQL query with input .xlsx file like sheetjs demo(https://sheetjs.com/sexql/index.html) and i have no idea how to do it.

I tried so many things but none of them worked.

```
    $('#input-excel').change(function(e){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                    var wb = XLSX.read(data,{type:'array'});
                    var htmlstr = XLSX.write(wb,{sheet:"Sheet2", type:'binary',bookType:'csv'});
                    $('#wrapper')[0].innerHTML += htmlstr;
                    var res = alasql('SELECT * FROM ?',htmlstr);
                    console.log(res);         
            }

    });
```

I tried to use AlaSQL but it didn't work. It only takes files not sheetJS variables.

Comment: Does it work: https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/XLSX ? What error do you have? It is need more details in your question.